# SimpleHTTPServer in Python3.6.4 can not handle non-ASCII string(Chinese in my case)

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, webserver, simplehttpserver

I run SimpleHTTPServer in Python3.6.4 64bit by this command:

> python -m http.server --cgi

then I make a form in test.py, submit it to test_form_action.py to print the input text.

cgi-bin/test.py

```
# coding=utf-8
from __future__ import unicode_literals, absolute_import

print("Content-Type: text/html")  # HTML is following
print()
reshtml = '''<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<div style="text-align: center;">
    <form action="/cgi-bin/test_form_action.py" method="POST"
          target="_blank">
        输入:<input type="text" id= "id" name="name"/></td>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>'''

print(reshtml)
```

cgi-bin/test_form_action.py

```
# coding=utf-8
from __future__ import unicode_literals, absolute_import

# Import modules for CGI handling
import cgi, cgitb
cgitb.enable()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Content-Type: text/html")  # HTML is following
    print()

    form = cgi.FieldStorage()
    print(form)
    id = form.getvalue("id")
    name = form.getvalue("name")

    print(id)
```

When I visit http://127.0.0.1:8000/cgi-bin/test.py,
The Chinese Character "输入" doesn't show right, it look like "����",
I have to manually change the Text Encoding of this page from 
"Unicode" to "Chinese Simplified" in Firefox to make Chinese Character look normal.

It's weird, since I put charset="utf-8" in cgi-bin/test.py.

Further more, when I put some Chinese in input form, and submit. But cgi-bin/test_form_action.py is blank.

meanwhile some error show in windows terminal where I run SimpleHTTPServer:

> 127.0.0.1 - - [23/Mar/2018 23:43:32] b'Error in sys.excepthook:\r\nTraceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File
>   "E:\Python\Python36\Lib\cgitb.py", line 26 8, in **call**\r\n
>   self.handle((etype, evalue, etb))\r\n  File
>   "E:\Python\Python36\Lib\cgitb.py", line 288, in handle\r\n
>   self.file.write(doc + \'\ n\')\r\nUnicodeEncodeError: \'gbk\' codec
>   can\'t encode character \'\ufffd\' in position 1894: illegal
>   multibyte sequence\r\n\r\nOriginal exception was:\r\nT raceback (most
>   recent call last):\r\n  File
>   "G:\Python\Project\VideoHelper\cgi-bin\test_form_action.py", line
>   13, in \r\n    print(form)\r\nUnico deEncodeError: \'gbk\'
>   codec can\'t encode character \'\ufffd\' in position 52: illegal
>   multibyte sequence\r\n'
>   127.0.0.1 - - [23/Mar/2018 23:43:32] CGI script exit status 0x1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the `print()` expression, Python converts the strings to bytes, ie. it `encode`s them using a default codec.
The choice of this default value depends on the environment – in your case it seems to be GBK (judging from the error message).

In the HTML page your CGI script returns, you specify the codec ("charset") as UTF-8.
You can of course change this to GBK, but it will only solve your first problem (display of test.py), not the second one (encoding error in test_form_action.py).
Instead, it's probably better to get Python to send UTF-8-encoded data on STDOUT.

One approach is to replace all occurrences of

```
print(x)
```

with

```
sys.stdout.buffer.write(x.encode('utf8'))
```

Alternatively, you can replace `sys.stdout` with a re-encoded wrapper, without changing the `print()` occurrences:

```
sys.stdout = open(sys.stdout.buffer.fileno(), 'w', encoding='utf8'))
```

**Note:** These two solutions don't work in Python 2.x (you'd have to omit the `.buffer` part there).
I'm writing this because your code has `from __future__ import` statements, which have no use in code that is run with Python 3 exclusively.

Comment: Thank for you explain. I am using Python3.6.4, so I put your code:sys.stdout = open(sys.stdout.fileno(), 'w', encoding='utf8') before I use print(), then every Chinese Character is work fine. I didn't expect codec could be some complicate in Python3.

Comment: I'm glad if it helped. The `print()` function is designed to work with your terminal, so Python tries to be clever and sync the standard-channel config with your environment. This makes life easier most of the time, but apparently not in your particular situation.

Comment: Since the default depends on the environment, you could achieve this through setting environment variables (eg. `PYTHONIOENCODING`). I'm not sure how to specifically do this on Windows, though. Anyway, it's probably a good idea to do this inside a [virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html).