# Cannot encode or use string as it is

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I am retrieving some texts from a database, while using python3 I saw some errors like this:

```
forgelogger\\n    print("%s | %s" % (time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), message))\\nUnicodeEncodeError: \\'ascii\\' codec can\\'t encode character \\'\\\\xad\\' in position 62: ordinal not in range(128)'
```

After that I tried using the variables as they are, and also trying to `.encode()`, but then I get:

```
TypeError: must be str, not bytes
```

I also tried using `.decode()` but then:

```
AttributeError: \\'str\\' object has no attribute \\'decode\\''
```

I cannot see which is the problematic character.

This used to work with `unicode()` on python2, but not anymore. 
Any suggestion?

EDIT:
If it helps, this is the configuration of Trac (It is its database that we are querying):

```
default_charset = iso-8859-15
```

Comment: Some code around the errormessage please. So I/we can give you a example for solving.

Comment: If the message is `TypeError: must be str, not bytes` then the value is already encoded.

Comment: Can you check sys.stdout.encoding? It is probably set to ascii, which can't encode unicode.

Comment: When you use the `print()` function, the strings are encoded automatically using a default codec. This default depends a number of environment variables, so it's a bit unpredictable when you port a script to somewhere else. I'm sure there are a lot of posts on SO on many variations of this problem; one of them is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49470228/1698431) I just posted very recently.

Comment: `\xad` mentioned in the error message is a format  character  _Soft Hyphen_ (Unicode `U+00AD`, UTF-8 sequence `\xC2\xAD`).